# I want to install the tub below with surround. How can I install the surround on only two walls leaving the end open?

Tags: bathroom

[image]
[image]

These are the tub surround and tub style that I want to install.

Also does tub need to have its own CB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About what kind of breaker you need - read the manual for the tub.  It will list how many amps the breaker should be and what wire gauge to use.  You are going to be sitting in a box full of water and electricity, so ensure those instructions are followed to the letter.

You typically need a dedicated GFI circuit breaker for a tub.  We have a similar tub, and that GFI has undoubtedly saved our lives when water managed to get into the air blower motor.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt use this surround to modify.  The crown up top will not look right unless maybe there is a 3" bump out from the wall.  Surrounds are suppose to be quick and easy. This one is not cheap either. You should do it right and install tile it will probably be same price if not cheaper. Yes jetted tubs are suppose to have a dedicated circuit.

Comment: Thank you. I will most likely go with tile. The tub says 7 amp so do I need a special CB?

Comment: When I put mine in I didnt.  But direction say too.